# Service Функции в Service и их вызов в не Service

Tags: java, android

Как написать функцию из Service и потом ее вызывать из любой активности...
Тоесть Service включен, работает, в нем важные переменные которые не должны выгружатся,и есть функции для работы с ними, и как вызвать именно эту функцию из любой активности... запись на sd или data не выход, в одном из переменных находится httpclient с важными куками...
Также может кто-то расскажет как сделать сервис автозапускаемым и проводить через него некие операции через время.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Получить экземпляр работающего сервиса (с доступом ко всем публичным полям и методам) можно с помощью Binder. Гуглить надо "android  bind service"
2. Автозапуск можно реализовать подписавшись на событие загрузки девайса. Гуглить: "receive boot compelete android"
3. Запуск кода по расписанию можно через AlarmManager реализовать. Гуглим "android AlarmManager"

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Логов тьма, но строчка такова      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ux.uchat.Autorizes.onCreate(Autorizes.java:32)

Comment: Я так понел сервис не успевает стартануть, как сделать фитчу чтобы код ждал пока сервис загрузится?

Comment: В комментах это не решить. Создайте новый вопрос.